# Prevent SonarQube from failing Pull Request checks

Tags: jenkins, github, sonarqube

I've set up an automatic "pull request check" via jenkins/github/sonarqube integration.
The workflow is as follows:
Github pull request created by user → Github Webhook triggers, and calls Jenkins API to execute sonarqube scanner → reports to sonarqube server → sonarqube server calls github API(create commit statuses : ref https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/) and posts a comment about the PR.

The issue is that it marks the PR as check failed just because it didn't pass its code health checks. The build passed, but the code is "dirty" - and that causes the PR to be marked as unacceptable. **I'd like to find a way to prevent code quality checks from appearing as an actual status of the commit, and only allow commenting.**

Additional images to provide some context:

SonarQube uses a techuser account token to post its analysis summary as a comment on the PR thread. (Sorry for the black boxes, corporate stuff..)
This functionality is everything we need, nothing more.
[image]

However... the plugin does one more thing, which is marking the commit as a failure. Note that we're already using something else to check for actual build failures. Although it didn't fail, sonarqube marking the commit as failure because of code quality makes the whole commit display as a failure. I'd like to prevent sonarqube from setting branch check statuses, while letting it comment on the issue. I couldn't find an option for anything like that neither in jenkins plugin configuration nor sonarqube admin page nor sonarqube scanner script documentation.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to achieve is currently not possible when using the [SonarQube GitHub plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin), since this behaviour is hardcoded in the plugin and there is no configuration option to customize this.

In upcoming versions of SonarQube and SonarCloud, pull request will have a built-in support and the behaviour will be the following:

- The status will be red if there is at least an open issue on the PR analyzed by SonarQube/SonarCloud
- Teams will have the ability to mark those issues as "Confirmed" in SonarQube/SonarCloud (to acknowledge that they accept this technical debt), in which case the status will be automatically turned to green in GitHub

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. I'll be looking forward to future releases.